# Converting html to xls using xsl

Tags: html, xslt

I have the following requirement.

input will be

```
———
———

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            …………..
            …………...
        </tr>
            …………..
            …………...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            …………..
            …………...
        </tr>
            …………..
            …………... 
    </tbody>
</table>

———
———
```

like this multiple tables.

Now I need to create different worksheets (for workbook / Excel file) for different tables. no of worksheets depends on no of tables. I need to do this using Xslt.

No of tables are not constant it will differ.

If you have any idea please let me know. I did some research in the Internet, but I couldn’t find anything.

I wrote the following xsl. I was able to generate multiple sheets. But the table is only printed on the first sheet. I want to have the table over all sheets.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xsd exslt fn php SOAP-ENV rs">

    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <!-- 
        Beginning of template processing, start at document root
    //-->
        <xsl:variable name="pageBreakAfterTable">false</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:template match="/">

        </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">  
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
                xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
                xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" 
                xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"&gt;
            &lt;head&gt;
                &lt;meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"&gt;
                &lt;meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet&gt;
                &lt;meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 11"&gt;

                &lt;!--[if gte mso 9]&gt;&lt;xml&gt;
                 &lt;x:ExcelWorkbook&gt;
                  &lt;x:ExcelWorksheets&gt;
                </xsl:text>

            <xsl:for-each select="//html/body/table">
                                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                                &lt;x:ExcelWorksheet&gt;
                    &lt;x:Name&gt;Report Results&lt;/x:Name&gt;
                    &lt;x:WorksheetOptions&gt;
                     &lt;x:Selected/&gt;
                     &lt;x:ShowGridlines/&gt;
                     &lt;x:ProtectContents&gt;False&lt;/x:ProtectContents&gt;
                     &lt;x:ProtectObjects&gt;False&lt;/x:ProtectObjects&gt;
                     &lt;x:ProtectScenarios&gt;False&lt;/x:ProtectScenarios&gt;
                    &lt;/x:WorksheetOptions&gt;
                                </xsl:text> 
                                <xsl:element name="table">
                <xsl:call-template name="processRows">
                    <xsl:with-param name="rows" select="./thead/tr"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="processRows">
                    <xsl:with-param name="rows" select="./tbody/tr"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="processRows">
                    <xsl:with-param name="rows" select="./tr"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:element name="tr"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/x:ExcelWorksheet&gt;</xsl:text>

            </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
                        &lt;/x:ExcelWorksheets&gt;
                  &lt;x:ProtectStructure&gt;False&lt;/x:ProtectStructure&gt;
                  &lt;x:ProtectWindows&gt;False&lt;/x:ProtectWindows&gt;
                 &lt;/x:ExcelWorkbook&gt;
                &lt;/xml&gt;&lt;![endif]--&gt;

            &lt;/head&gt;
            &lt;body&gt;</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</xsl:text>

        <!-- Translate each table -->
<!--        <xsl:call-template name="processTables">
            <xsl:with-param name="tables" select="//html/body/table"/>
        </xsl:call-template>-->


    </xsl:template>

<!--    <xsl:template name="processTables">  
        <xsl:param name="tables"/>

    </xsl:template>-->

    <xsl:template name="processRows">
        <xsl:param name="rows"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="$rows">
            <xsl:if test="not(contains(@class,'emptyValue'))">

                <xsl:element name="tr">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                        <!-- Do we need to display a drill-down depth? -->
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="count(./node()[contains(@class,'ds-drilldown-level-6')]) &gt; 0">
                                <xsl:text>mso-outline-level:6;</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="count(./node()[contains(@class,'ds-drilldown-level-5')]) &gt; 0">
                                <xsl:text>mso-outline-level:5;</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="count(./node()[contains(@class,'ds-drilldown-level-4')]) &gt; 0">
                                <xsl:text>mso-outline-level:4;</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="count(./node()[contains(@class,'ds-drilldown-level-3')]) &gt; 0">
                                <xsl:text>mso-outline-level:3;</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="count(./node()[contains(@class,'ds-drilldown-level-2')]) &gt; 0">
                                <xsl:text>mso-outline-level:2;</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:when test="count(./node()[contains(@class,'ds-drilldown-level-1')]) &gt; 0">
                                <xsl:text>mso-outline-level:1;</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <xsl:for-each select="./node()">
                        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != '' or normalize-space(@*) != ''">
                            <xsl:element name="td">
                                <xsl:if test="@colspan">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="@colspan"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="@rowspan">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="@rowspan"/>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="name(.)='td'">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="align"><xsl:text>right</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:attribute name="style">
                                    <xsl:if test="name(.)='th'">
                                        <xsl:text> font-weight:bold;</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="contains(@class,' red')">
                                        <xsl:text> color:red;</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="contains(@class,' green')">
                                        <xsl:text> color:green;</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:attribute>

                                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please perform some research and provide sample of your attempt to code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which I wrote. Based on variable we can get the data either in single sheet or in multiple sheets.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
                xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
                xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
                xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
                xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
        <!-- 
        Beginning of template processing, start at document root
    //-->
        <xsl:param name="pageBreakAfterTable" select="0"/>

        <xsl:template match="/">  
            <Workbook>
                <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
                    <LastAuthor>Intervolve</LastAuthor>
                </DocumentProperties>
                <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
                    <AllowPNG/>
                </OfficeDocumentSettings>
                <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
                    <WindowHeight>10880</WindowHeight>
                    <WindowWidth>25600</WindowWidth>
                    <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
                    <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
                    <ActiveSheet>0</ActiveSheet>
                    <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
                    <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
               </ExcelWorkbook>
                <Styles>
                    <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
                        <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
                        <Borders/>
                        <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000"/>
                        <Interior/>
                        <NumberFormat/>
                        <Protection/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style ss:ID="s62">
                        <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style ss:ID="s63">
                        <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                        <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style ss:ID="s64">
                        <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style ss:ID="s65">
                        <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                        <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Color="#DD0806"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style ss:ID="s66">
                        <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                        <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Color="#1FB714"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style ss:ID="s67">
                        <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                        <NumberFormat ss:Format="Standard"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style ss:ID="s68">
                        <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                        <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#DD0806"/>
                        <NumberFormat ss:Format="Standard"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style ss:ID="s69">
                        <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                        <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#1FB714"/>
                        <NumberFormat ss:Format="Standard"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style ss:ID="s70">
                        <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                        <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#1FB714"/>
                        <NumberFormat ss:Format="Percent"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style ss:ID="s71">
                        <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                        <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#DD0806"/>
                        <NumberFormat ss:Format="Percent"/>
                    </Style>
                </Styles>
                <xsl:if test="$pageBreakAfterTable=1">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//table" />
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$pageBreakAfterTable=0">
                    <xsl:call-template name="processTables">
            <xsl:with-param name="tables" select="//html/body/table"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </Workbook>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="processTables">  
        <xsl:param name="tables"/>
                <Worksheet ss:Name="Report Results">
                    <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="{count(.//tr/th)}" ss:ExpandedRowCount="{count(.//tr)}" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">

                        <xsl:for-each select="$tables">
    <!--                                <Column ss:Width="138"/>
                                    <Column ss:Width="260"/>-->
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//tr" />
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </Table>
        <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">

                    <PageLayoutZoom>0</PageLayoutZoom>
                    <TopRowVisible>0</TopRowVisible>
                    <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
                    <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
                </WorksheetOptions>
            </Worksheet>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="table">
            <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet{count(preceding::table) + 1}">
                <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="{count(.//tr/th)}" ss:ExpandedRowCount="{count(.//tr)}" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
                    <Column ss:Width="138"/>
                    <Column ss:Width="260"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//tr" />
                </Table>
                <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">

                    <PageLayoutZoom>0</PageLayoutZoom>
                    <TopRowVisible>0</TopRowVisible>
                    <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
                    <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
                </WorksheetOptions>
            </Worksheet>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="tr">
            <Row>
                <xsl:for-each select="./node()">
                    <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != '' or normalize-space(@*) != ''">
                        <Cell>
                            <xsl:attribute name="ss:MergeAcross">
                                <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="@colspan > 1"><xsl:value-of select="@colspan - 1" /></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="ss:MergeDown">
                                <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="@rowspan > 1"><xsl:value-of select="@rowspan - 1" /></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:attribute>

                            <xsl:attribute name="ss:StyleID">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="name(.)='th'">s63</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="contains(@class,' green')">
                                                <xsl:choose>
                                                    <xsl:when test="contains(text(),'%')">s70</xsl:when>
                                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                                        <xsl:choose>
                                                            <xsl:when test="contains(@class,' numeric')">s69</xsl:when>
                                                            <xsl:otherwise>s66</xsl:otherwise>
                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                                </xsl:choose>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                <xsl:choose>
                                                    <xsl:when test="contains(@class,' red')">
                                                        <xsl:choose>
                                                            <xsl:when test="contains(text(),'%')">s71</xsl:when>
                                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                <xsl:choose>
                                                                    <xsl:when test="contains(@class,' numeric')">s68</xsl:when>
                                                                    <xsl:otherwise>s65</xsl:otherwise>
                                                                </xsl:choose>
                                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                    </xsl:when>
                                                    <xsl:otherwise>s62</xsl:otherwise>
                                                </xsl:choose>
                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                            <Data>
                                <xsl:attribute name="ss:Type">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="contains(text(),'%')">String</xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:choose>
                                                <xsl:when test="contains(@class,' numeric')">Number</xsl:when>
                                                <xsl:otherwise>String</xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                            </Data>
                        </Cell>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </Row>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can simplify that rather nested `xsl:choose` for creating the "MergeAcross" attribute to just `<xsl:attribute name="ss:MergeAcross"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="@colspan > 1"><xsl:value-of select="@colspan - 1" /></xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></xsl:attribute>`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach in disabling output escaping to do the output is not a recommended approach, not least because it makes the XML extremely hard to read. It also looks like you add HTML to your Excel spreadsheet. Excel can import HTML, I believe, but it may be better to use "XML Spreadsheet 2003" format here.

Firstly, you need to get Excel to do the hard-work for you. Open up Excel, enter some test data to represent what you want your table to look like, then save it in "XML Spreadsheet 2003" format. You can then open it in Notepad to see what Excel expects. Indeed, you can copy and paste a lot of it into Excel.

The approach you need to take in your XSLT is a template based approach. First start off by matching **body** elements. In the template you can output the **Workbook** element, and include an **xsl:apply-templates** to look for any **table** elements. For example

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <Workbook>
        <!-- More properties here -->
        <Styles>
            <!-- Styles here -->
        </Styles>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//table" />
    </Workbook>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, the template matching **table** will be used to output. Note the use of "Attribute Value Templates** to calculate the number of columns and rows

```
<xsl:template match="table">
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet{count(preceding::table) + 1}">
        <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="{count(thead/tr/th)}" ss:ExpandedRowCount="{count(.//tr)}" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//tr" />
        </Table>
        <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <!-- options -->
        </WorksheetOptions>
    </Worksheet>
</xsl:template>
```

You can then carry on with this approach, with templates matching **tr** being used to output **Row** elements, and templates matching **td** (or **th**) used to output **Cell** elements.

Try this XSLT for starters

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
                xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
                xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
                xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
                xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <Workbook>
            <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
                <Author>Test</Author>
                <LastAuthor>Test</LastAuthor>
                <Created>2014-06-20T12:40:11Z</Created>
                <Version>14.00</Version>
            </DocumentProperties>
            <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
                <AllowPNG/>
            </OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
                <WindowHeight>4680</WindowHeight>
                <WindowWidth>16275</WindowWidth>
                <WindowTopX>120</WindowTopX>
                <WindowTopY>120</WindowTopY>
                <ActiveSheet>1</ActiveSheet>
                <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
                <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
            </ExcelWorkbook>
            <Styles>
                <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
                    <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
                    <Borders/>
                    <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
                    <Interior/>
                    <NumberFormat/>
                    <Protection/>
                </Style>
            </Styles>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//table" />
        </Workbook>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet{count(preceding::table) + 1}">
            <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="{count(thead/tr/th)}" ss:ExpandedRowCount="{count(.//tr)}" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".//tr" />
            </Table>
            <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
                <PageSetup>
                    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
                    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
                    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
                 </PageSetup>
                <Panes>
                    <Pane>
                        <Number>3</Number>
                        <ActiveRow>1</ActiveRow>
                        <ActiveCol>2</ActiveCol>
                    </Pane>
                </Panes>
                <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
                <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
            </WorksheetOptions>
        </Worksheet>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tr">
        <Row>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="th|td" />
        </Row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="th|td">
        <Cell>
            <Data ss:Type="String"><xsl:value-of select="." /></Data>
        </Cell>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This does assumes your tables are fairly well structured. It would become more complex if you had **colspan** and **rowspan** present.

Comment: Hi Tim, As you said, now stuck with colspan and rowspan. if you give some idea on that that will be much greatful

Comment: What I would suggest is create a new Excel worksheet, and merge some cells, either in the same row, or the same column, and see what XML is generated. I think `colspan='2'` is generated as `ss:MergeAcross='1'` on the Cell element, and `rowspan='2'`becomes `ss:MergeDown='1'`. If you can't get it to work, feel free to ask a whole new question here on StackOverflow showing what you have tried. Thanks!

Comment: Hi  Tim C, is it possible to impliment row group and outline? (which comes in Data menu popdown.) Thanks Hari

Comment: The answer is probably "Yes" but personally I don't know much about row groups and outlines in Excel. I suggest you try as I mentioned before; create an Excel spreadsheet with the features, save it as XML, and open that in a text editor to see how it works. If you can't work it out, it is best to ask a whole new question. Thank you.